# Request for the permission of type 'ReflectionPermission' failed

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

I have been using the Linq To Sql in my web project. My Application works local system fine but it doesn't work on the hosting sytem where i hosted it actually.

Please help. Does this have anything to do with IIS ?

Regards

Comment: it has to do with permissions/rights - these seem to be different between you local system and the hosting system...

Answer (score 1):

Please see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907622.aspx), under the *LINQ and Code-access Security* section.

You should ask your system administrator to change the trust level of your application or just add the required ReflectionPermission on the configuration file for the machine.